# Pitfalls in R for Python programmers

Tags: python, r

I have mostly programmed in Python, but I am now learning the statistical programming language R. I have noticed some difference between the languages that tend to trip me.

Suppose `v` is a vector/array with the integers from 1 to 5 inclusive.

```
v[3]  # in R: gives me the 3rd element of the vector: 3
      # in Python: is zero-based, gives me the integer 4
v[-1] # in R: removes the element with that index
      # in Python: gives me the last element in the array
```

Are there any other pitfalls I have to watch out for?

Comment: `v[3]` in python gives you fourth element of a sequence. in the given case that would be `4`.

Comment: @SilentGhost: off course, fixed the mistake.

Comment: The title does not accuractely represent the question here - these are not "pitfalls in R", they are just basic differences between two different languages. And anyway, v[-1] does not "remove the element" with index 1, it returns a new vector with every element but the first one.

Comment: @mdsumner: I totally disagree. If your vector v has 100M elements, then 'accidentally' implicitly creating a new vector v[-1] with 100M-1 elements would be slow as well as painful as well as wrong. So, it is a pitfall.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Having written tens of thousands of lines of code in both languages, R is just a lot more idiosyncratic and less consistent than Python. It's really nice for doing quick plots and investigation on a small to medium size dataset, mainly because its built-in dataframe object is nicer than the numpy/scipy equivalent, but you'll find all kinds of weirdness as you do things more complicated than one liners. My advice is to use [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) (which unfortunately has a much worse UI than its predecessor, rpy) and just do as little as possible in R with the rest in Python.

For example, consider the following matrix code:

```
> u = matrix(1:9,nrow=3,ncol=3)
> v = u[,1:2]
> v[1,1]
[2] 1
> w = u[,1]
> w[1,1]
Error in w[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

How did that fail? The reason is that if you select a submatrix from a matrix which has only one column along any given axis, R "helpfully" drops that column and changes the type of the variable. So w is a vector of integers rather than a matrix:

```
> class(v)
[1] "matrix"
> class(u)
[1] "matrix"
> class(w)
[1] "integer"
```

To avoid this, you need to actually pass an obscure keyword parameter:

```
> w2 = u[,1,drop=FALSE]
> w2[1,1]
[3] 1
> class(w2)
[1] "matrix"
```

There's a lot of nooks and crannies like that. Your best friend at the beginning will be introspection and online help tools like `str`,`class`,`example`, and of course `help`. Also, make sure to look at the example code on the [R Graph Gallery](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/thumbs.php) and in Ripley's [Modern Applied Statistics with S-Plus](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS4/) book.

---

**EDIT**: Here's another great example with factors.

```
> xx = factor(c(3,2,3,4))
> xx
[1] 3 2 3 4
Levels: 2 3 4
> yy = as.numeric(xx)
> yy
[1] 2 1 2 3
```

Holy cow! Converting something from a factor back to a numeric didn't actually do the conversion you thought it would. Instead it's doing it on the internal enumerated type of the factor. This is a source of hard-to-find bugs for people who aren't aware of this, because it's still returning integers and will in fact actually work *some* of the time (when the input is already numerically ordered).

This is what you actually need to do

```
> as.numeric(levels(xx))[xx]
[1] 3 2 3 4
```

Yeah, sure, that fact is on the `factor` help page, but you only land up there when you've lost a few hours to this bug. This is another example of how R does not do what you intend. Be very, very careful with anything involving type conversions or accessing elements of arrays and lists.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's especially a personal opinion. You can indeed not be happy with some defaults, or find it "less idiosyncratic", but for what it's designed R outperforms Python in _my_ personal opinion. I just got used to how R works, and as you most often select a row or column from a matrix to do a **vectorized** calculation on it, the default drop=T isn't all that unlogic.

Comment: Well, sure, but you can multiply an n x 1 matrix just as well as you can a length n vector. There's no reason to force a type conversion.

Anyway, let's just say this is not the behavior in any other matrix language library (including numpy) and is hence relevant to the author's original question re: pitfalls :)

Comment: "for what it's designed R outperforms Python"

Absolutely, and I'm not denying that. For a quick investigation of a dataset or for statistical graphics, R is unmatched. My only advice is that once you're done, you want to keep any production use of R siloed away in individual function calls to rpy2.

Comment: the `R Graph Gallery` seems to go to a dead end.

Answer (score 14):

This isn't specifically addressing the Python vs. R background, but the [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) is a great resource for programmers coming to R.

Comment: +1 for R Inferno pointer -- a great reference for R "pitfalls"

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer to this post is possibly a bit outdated. The [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) Python library now provides amazing R-like DataFrame support.

Answer (score 1):

There may be... but before you embark on that have you tried some of the available Python extensions?  [Scipy](http://www.scipy.org/Topical_Software#head-0da0d03b4980ca16c9419ebe6cb760dd5bbf34c7) has a list.